# Add Interval month or day

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to add two dates based on a single static value and a second decoded value.

I would use add_months, but it doesn't play well with the 2 week period.

```
to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + DECODE(visit_name,'0WK',interval '0' day,'2WK',interval '14' day,'1MO',interval '1' month, '1YR', interval '1' year) as due_date
```

The problem with the above code is that it won't let me use more than one interval type. If I stick to days it works, but as soon as I add in month or year it breaks. Considering the variable length of months the final calculated date will be wrong for some time periods if I try to say '30 day for a month.

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intervals with months and years can be tricky anyway; if your procedure date was 2015-08-31 and you added a month you'd get an invalid date (as September doesn't have 31 days); similarly if you had 2016-02-29 and added a year you'd have the same problem.

It might be simpler to switch from adding days for the two-week period instead of using an interval; and using `add_months` for the months and years, inside a simple case expression rather than a decode (though that would work too):

```
case visit_name
  when '0WK' then to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
  when '2WK' then to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 14
  when '1MO' then add_months(to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1)
  when '1YR' then add_months(to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 12)
end as due_date
```

It's repeating the `to_date()` part - but you should have dates stored as the correct data type rather than as strings anyway, so this is just part of the price you pay...

With some dummy data:

```
with t (procedure_date, visit_name) as (
  select '03-Apr-2015', '2WK' from dual
  union all select '10-Jul-2015', '0WK' from dual
  union all select '15-Aug-2015', '1MO' from dual
  union all select '27-Jan-2015', '1YR' from dual
)
select procedure_date, visit_name,
  case visit_name
    when '0WK' then to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
    when '2WK' then to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') + 14
    when '1MO' then add_months(to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1)
    when '1YR' then add_months(to_date(procedure_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 12)
    end as due_date
from t;

PROCEDURE_D VIS DUE_DATE 
----------- --- ----------
03-Apr-2015 2WK 2015-04-17
10-Jul-2015 0WK 2015-07-10
15-Aug-2015 1MO 2015-09-15
27-Jan-2015 1YR 2016-01-27
```